# RestTemplate POSTing entity with associations to Spring Data REST server

Tags: json, rest, jackson, resttemplate, spring-data-rest

### The problem

I have three entities (taken from the [Spring Data REST Exporter Example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest-webmvc)): Person, Address and Profile. A Person can have addresses and profiles.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Version
    private Long version;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Address> addresses;
    @OneToMany
    private Map<String, Profile> profiles;

    // getters and setters
}
```

In the client side I use Spring's [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). I added the [Jackson2HalModule](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/hal/Jackson2HalModule.html) to the ObjectMapper used by the  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter used by my RestTemplate.

Since Address and Profile do not have references to other entities I can POST them to my Spring Data REST server, and they are successfully saved:

```
final ResponseEntity<Resource<Address>> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/addresses",
                addressInstance, AddressResource.class);
```

where `AddressResource extends org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<Address>`.

But when I try to POST a Person instance

```
final ResponseEntity<Resource<Person>> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/people",
                personInstance, PersonResource.class);
```

I get a `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request` and I think the cause is the associated `Address`es and `Profile`s
 are serialized as normal POJOs instead as their resource URIs.

Here is the actual body of the POST request:

```
{
   "id":null,
   "name":"Jongjin Han",
   "version":null,
   "addresses":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "lines":[
            "1111",
            "coder's street"
         ],
         "city":"San Diego",
         "province":"California",
         "postalCode":"60707"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "lines":[
            "1111",
            "coder's street"
         ],
         "city":"San Diego",
         "province":"California",
         "postalCode":"60707"
      }
   ],
   "profiles":{
      "key1":{
         "type":"a type of profile",
         "url":"http://www.profileurl.com"
      },
      "key2":{
         "type":"a type of profile",
         "url":"http://www.profileurl.com"
      }
   }
}
```

I think it should be --> **EDIT: It should be**

```
{
   "id":null,
   "name":"Jongjin Han",
   "version":null,
   "addresses":[
      "http://localhost:8080/addresses/1",
      "http://localhost:8080/addresses/2"
   ],
   "profiles":{
      "key1":"http://localhost:8080/profiles/1",
      "key2":"http://localhost:8080/profiles/2"
   }
}
```

in fact the response body from the server is

```
{
  "cause" : {
    "cause" : {
      "cause" : {
        "cause" : null,
        "message" : "Cannot resolve URI id. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable."
      },
      "message" : "Failed to convert from type java.net.URI to type org.springframework.data.rest.example.model.Address for value 'id'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI id. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable."
    },
    "message" : "Failed to convert from type java.net.URI to type org.springframework.data.rest.example.model.Address for value 'id'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI id. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable. (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.example.model.Person[\"addresses\"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])"
  },
  "message" : "Could not read document: Failed to convert from type java.net.URI to type org.springframework.data.rest.example.model.Address for value 'id'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI id. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable. (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.example.model.Person[\"addresses\"]->java.util.ArrayList[1]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to convert from type java.net.URI to type org.springframework.data.rest.example.model.Address for value 'id'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI id. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable. (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.example.model.Person[\"addresses\"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])"
}
```

### The possible solution I'd like to implement

Since I can access the REST repositories from the client side I am looking for a way to **customize the Jackson Json Serializer** in order to:

- check if the object I am serializing is a REST exported entity (*easy with reflection, if only I could know where to put the code*) and
- If I am serializing an entity, serialize the non-association fields as usual (e.g. person's name) and the association fields as their Resource URI (e.g. person's addresses) (*with reflection it should be easy to convert from an entity to its resource URI, but I do not know where to put the code once again*)

I tried with Jackson's JsonSerializer and PropertyFilters for Address and Profile, but I want **a serializer which serialize them as resource URI only when they are in an association**.

Any hint or aternative solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Something is not configured correctly.

You should not have to POST HAL formatted data to get this to work, a plain old POJO serialized to JSON should work fine with the default configuration.

I would suggest using a proxy to intercept the request and confirm the structure.

Comment: In this way I should before POST the new association-free Person entity, and then PUT the associations references (so the links, not the POJOs). The JSON serialization with the URIs for the associations [is actually the right way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380599/spring-data-rest-manytomany-post) (question edited)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and tried to solve it with several techniques.
Implemented working solution - it's a dirty workaround so don't blame me for the quality of the code, probably I will clean it up later :)
I wanted to test Spring Data REST API and realized that MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ignores @Entity relations.
Setting serializer modifier didn't work correctly: null-value serializer didn't work and relations serialized with deep property serialization.

The idea of workaround is to provide CustomSerializerModifier which returns CustomSerializer for project @Entities (inherited from BaseEntity in this example). CustomSerializer performs following actions:

1. write null-values (because omits them)
2. provide array of related @Entities as List in Spring Data REST style (//)
3. execute serialize(...) of default MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter but providing NameTransformer which renames relations key (add ' _@ ') and then applies filter which excludes all fields starting with ' _@ '

I don't like this monster, but it works, and sadly I didn't find any solution :/

Working solution:

**BasicRestTest**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;
import com.meddis.util.serializer.CustomIgnorePropertyFilter;
import com.meddis.util.serializer.CustomSerializerModifier;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.hateoas.MediaTypes;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.mock.http.MockHttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "timezone = UTC"
})
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class BasicRestTest {

    protected String host = "localhost";

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    protected int port;

    @Value("${spring.data.rest.basePath}")
    protected String springDataRestBasePath;

    protected MediaType contentType = new MediaType("application", "hal+json", Charset.forName("utf8"));

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    private static HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;

    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    void setConverters(HttpMessageConverter<?>[] converters) {

        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        if (this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter == null) {
            this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("CUSTOM", Version.unknownVersion());
            simpleModule.setSerializerModifier(new CustomSerializerModifier(springDataRestBasePath));
            ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter).getObjectMapper()
                    .registerModule(simpleModule);

            FilterProvider fp = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("CUSTOM", new CustomIgnorePropertyFilter());
            ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter).getObjectMapper()
                    .setFilterProvider(fp);

            ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter).setPrettyPrint(true);
        }

        assertNotNull("the JSON message converter must not be null", this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    protected String json(final Object o) throws IOException {
        MockHttpOutputMessage mockHttpOutputMessage = new MockHttpOutputMessage();
        this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.write(o, MediaTypes.HAL_JSON, mockHttpOutputMessage);
        return mockHttpOutputMessage.getBodyAsString();
    }
}
```

**CustomSerializerModifier**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;
import com.meddis.model.BaseEntity;

public class CustomSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {

    private final String springDataRestBasePath;

    public CustomSerializerModifier(final String springDataRestBasePath) {
        this.springDataRestBasePath = springDataRestBasePath;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
        if (BaseEntity.class.isAssignableFrom(beanDesc.getBeanClass())) {
            return new CustomSerializer((JsonSerializer<Object>) serializer, springDataRestBasePath);
        }
        return serializer;
    }
}
```

**CustomSerializer**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.NameTransformer;
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import com.meddis.model.BaseEntity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.*;

public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    private final JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer;

    private final String springDataRestBasePath;

    public CustomSerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer, final String springDataRestBasePath) {
        this.defaultSerializer = Preconditions.checkNotNull(defaultSerializer);
        this.springDataRestBasePath = springDataRestBasePath;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object baseEntity, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();

        Set<String> nestedEntityKeys = new HashSet<>();

        Arrays.asList(baseEntity.getClass().getMethods()).stream()
                .filter(field -> field.getName().startsWith("get"))
                .filter(field -> !Arrays.asList("getClass", "getVersion").contains(field.getName()))
                .forEach(field -> {
                    try {
                        Object value = field.invoke(baseEntity, new Object[]{});
                        String fieldName = field.getName().replaceAll("^get", "");
                        fieldName = fieldName.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + fieldName.substring(1);
                        if (value == null) {
                            jsonGenerator.writeObjectField(fieldName, null);
                        } else if (Iterable.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
                            Iterator it = ((Iterable) value).iterator();
                            // System.out.println(field.getName() + field.invoke(baseEntity, new Object[]{}));
                            List<String> nestedUris = new ArrayList<>();
                            it.forEachRemaining(nestedValue -> {
                                if (BaseEntity.class.isAssignableFrom(nestedValue.getClass())) {
                                    try {
                                        String nestedEntityStringDataName = nestedValue.getClass().getSimpleName() + "s";
                                        nestedEntityStringDataName = nestedEntityStringDataName.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + nestedEntityStringDataName.substring(1);
                                        Long nestedId = (long) nestedValue.getClass().getMethod("getId").invoke(nestedValue, new Object[]{});
                                        String nestedEntitySpringDataPath = springDataRestBasePath + "/" + nestedEntityStringDataName + "/" + Long.toString(nestedId);
                                        nestedUris.add(nestedEntitySpringDataPath);
                                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            nestedEntityKeys.add(fieldName);
                            jsonGenerator.writeObjectField(fieldName, nestedUris);
                        }
                    } catch (Throwable ignored) {
                    }
                });

        // Apply default serializer
        ((JsonSerializer<Object>) defaultSerializer.unwrappingSerializer(new NameTransformer() {
            @Override
            public String transform(String s) {
                if (nestedEntityKeys.contains(s)) {
                    return "_@" + s;
                }
                return s;
            }

            @Override
            public String reverse(String s) {
                if (nestedEntityKeys.contains(s.substring(2))) {
                    return s.substring(2);
                }
                return s;
            }
        }).withFilterId("CUSTOM")).serialize(baseEntity, jsonGenerator, serializerProvider);

        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

**CustomIgnorePropertyFilter**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonFormatVisitors.JsonObjectFormatVisitor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.PropertyWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;

public class CustomIgnorePropertyFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

    @Override
    public void serializeAsField(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider, PropertyWriter propertyWriter) throws Exception {
        if (propertyWriter.getName().startsWith("_@")) {
            return;
        }
        super.serializeAsField(o, jsonGenerator, serializerProvider, propertyWriter);
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeAsElement(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider, PropertyWriter propertyWriter) throws Exception {
        if (propertyWriter.getName().startsWith("_@")) {
            return;
        }
        super.serializeAsElement(o, jsonGenerator, serializerProvider, propertyWriter);
    }

    @Override
    public void depositSchemaProperty(PropertyWriter propertyWriter, ObjectNode objectNode, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws JsonMappingException {
        if (propertyWriter.getName().startsWith("_@")) {
            return;
        }
        super.depositSchemaProperty(propertyWriter, objectNode, serializerProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void depositSchemaProperty(PropertyWriter propertyWriter, JsonObjectFormatVisitor jsonObjectFormatVisitor, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws JsonMappingException {
        if (propertyWriter.getName().startsWith("_@")) {
            return;
        }
        super.depositSchemaProperty(propertyWriter, jsonObjectFormatVisitor, serializerProvider);
    }
}
```

**VideoStreamRestTest**

```
import com.meddis.AdminApiTest;
import com.meddis.model.VideoStream;
import com.meddis.repository.SpecialistRepository;
import com.meddis.repository.VideoStreamTagRepository;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

/**
 * <a href="https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/">example</a>
 */
public class VideoStreamRestTest extends AdminApiTest {

    @Autowired
    private SpecialistRepository specialistRepository;

    @Autowired
    private VideoStreamTagRepository videoStreamTagRepository;

    @Test
    public void springDataRestVideoStreams() throws Exception {
        String requestBody;
        String newEntityTitle = md5("VIDEO_STREAM_");
        MvcResult create = mockMvc.perform(post(springDataRestBasePath + "/videoStreams").headers(authenticationHeader)
                .content(requestBody = json(new VideoStream()
                        .setTitle(newEntityTitle)
                        .setType(VideoStream.Type.BROADCAST)
                        .setPrice(10.0)
                        .setDurationInMinutes(70)
                        .setDescription("broadcast description")
                        .setPreviewUrl("http://example.com")
                        .setSpecialists(StreamSupport.stream(specialistRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                        .setTags(StreamSupport.stream(videoStreamTagRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList())))))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andReturn();
        String createdLocation = create.getResponse().getHeader("Location");
        logger.info("Created new entity: {}", createdLocation);
        logger.info("Sent: {}", requestBody);

        MvcResult list = mockMvc.perform(get(springDataRestBasePath + "/videoStreams").headers(authenticationHeader))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.videoStreams", hasSize(greaterThanOrEqualTo(1))))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.videoStreams[*].title", hasItem(newEntityTitle)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.videoStreams[*]._links.self.href", hasItem(createdLocation)))
                .andReturn();
        logger.info("Got list containing new entity:\n{}", list.getResponse().getContentAsString());

        MvcResult createdEntity = mockMvc.perform(get(createdLocation).headers(authenticationHeader))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$._links.self.href", equalTo(createdLocation)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title", equalTo(newEntityTitle)))
                .andReturn();
        logger.info("Got new entity:\n{}", createdEntity.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }

}
```

**AdminApiTest**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

public abstract class AdminApiTest extends BasicRestTest {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    protected HttpHeaders authenticationHeader;

    @Before
    @Override
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        super.setup();
        this.authenticationHeader = createHeaderWithAuthentication();
    }

    protected HttpHeaders createHeaderWithAuthentication() throws IOException {
        String user = "pasha@pasha.ru";
        String password = "pasha";
        ResponseEntity<String> response = new TestRestTemplate()
                .postForEntity(
                        "http://" + host + ":" + port
                                + "login?"
                                + "&username=" + user
                                + "&password=" + password,
                        null,
                        String.class
                );
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.FOUND, response.getStatusCode());
        List<String> authenticationCookie = response.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");
        assertEquals(1, authenticationCookie.size());
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Cookie", authenticationCookie.get(0));
        return headers;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem, and the solution for me was to add  @RestResource(exported = false) to the association properity.

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Developer {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    @Column(length=20, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 3, message = "insufficient.size")
    @Size(max = 20, message = "maximum.size.exceeded")
    @NotEmpty(message = "compulsory.field")
    private String nickname;

    @Column(length=100, nullable = false)
    @Email(message = "invalid.field.value")
    @NotEmpty(message = "compulsory.field")
    private String email;

    private LocalDate dob;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "developer_skills",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "developer_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skills_uuid"))
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    private List<Skill> skills;

}


@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Skill {
    @Id @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false)
    private String uuid;

    @Column(length=20, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 1, message = "insufficient.size")
    @Size(max = 20, message = "maximum.size.exceeded")
    @NotEmpty(message = "compulsory.field")
    private String shortName;

    @Column(length=50, nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty(message = "compulsory.field")
    @Size(max = 50, message = "maximum.size.exceeded")
    private String name;

    @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT", nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 500, message = "maximum.size.exceeded")
    private String description;
}
```